# Unable to run the docker image for the ethereum project

Tags: python, django, linux, docker, ethereum

I have been trying to run the project 
https://github.com/Mattie432/Blockchain-Voting-System

The following steps are given to run the image.

> 1.Ensure docker is running with sudo service docker start.
>
> 2.Build the docker image with docker build -t applicationserver . while in the 2_ApplicationServer directory.
>
> 3.Run the docker image with docker run -p
>   80:80 applicationserver and map the internal port 80 to the localhost
>   port 80.

But following error is shown while the third step

```
docker run -p 80:80 applicationserver
[docker_entrypoint] Running database migrations..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/applicationserver/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/website/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from website.views import (Dashboard, HomepageRedirect)
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/website/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    import network.network_calls as NetworkRequest
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/network/network_calls.py", line 14, in <module>
    ballotregulator_ip       = os.environ[ 'TWISTED_BALLOTREGULATOR_IP' ]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TWISTED_BALLOTREGULATOR_IP'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 372, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 310, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 303, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/applicationserver/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/website/urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from website.views import (Dashboard, HomepageRedirect)
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/website/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    import network.network_calls as NetworkRequest
  File "/usr/src/applicationserver/network/network_calls.py", line 14, in <module>
    ballotregulator_ip       = os.environ[ 'TWISTED_BALLOTREGULATOR_IP' ]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TWISTED_BALLOTREGULATOR_IP'
[docker_entrypoint] Starting server..
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from wsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Thu Mar  8 19:05:51 2018] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 08 March 2018 19:04:56
os: Linux-4.13.0-21-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 18 17:29:16 UTC 2017
nodename: 327dd15d563c
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /usr/src/applicationserver
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /usr/src//applicationserver
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): No such file or directory [core/socket.c line 230]
```

Please help me with this.

**EDIT** : The Service has started using @Alasdair suggestion but how can I now map internal port 80 to localhost port 80

Comment: you're missing the `'TWISTED_BALLOTREGULATOR_IP'` variable in your environment

Comment: how can I add that, I am new to this, can you please help?

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs about it, that repo hasn't been updated in about a year also

Comment: it might be having the info in the paper folder, and then within Dissertation.pdf

Comment: You can set an environment variable with `docker run -p 80:80 -e "TWISTED_BALLOTREGULATOR_IP=1.2.3.4" 
 applicationserver`. However I don't think you'll be able to get help on Stack Overflow about *what* you should set it to. If you look at the repo, `TWISTED_BALLOTREGULATOR_IP` is set in the `docker-compose.yml`, so perhaps you should be using `docker-compose` instead of `docker` to run the project.

Comment: Thanks, Alasdair! the server had started but the mapping is not working